# Uploading a video to Youtube via Youtube api causing WebException - (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, youtube-api, youtube.net-api

I'm making a POC ASP.NET MVC application for uploading videos to Youtube.
When I try to upload a video I get a `GDataRequestException` with a `WebException` as inner exception. This is the message I got:

```
(500) Internal Server Error.
The stacktrace of the WebException is:

   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
```

Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult oauth2callback(string code)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
    {
         JObject json;

         NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection();
         postData.Add("code", code);
         postData.Add("client_id", "The client ID");
         postData.Add("client_secret", "The secret code");
         postData.Add("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:64896/home/oauth2callback");
         postData.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");

         json = JObject.Parse(
           HttpClient.PostUrl(
             new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"), postData));
         string accessToken = json["access_token"].ToString();
         string refreshToken = json["refresh_token"].ToString();
         bool isBearer =
           string.Compare(json["token_type"].ToString(),
                          "Bearer",
                          true,
                          CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) == 0;

         var settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("App name",
            "API key from simple API access", accessToken);
         var request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

         Video newVideo = new Video();
         newVideo.Title = "Test Video";
         newVideo.Keywords = "key 1 , key 2";

         newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Games", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));

         newVideo.Description = "Upload testing";
         newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;

         newVideo.Private = true; 

         newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new 
            MediaFileSource(@"C:\Users\Kaare\Videos\TestVideo1.avi", "video/x-msvideo");

         try
            {
                Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo); 
                return View();
            }                
            catch (GDataRequestException exp)
            {
               //Do something mening full

            }                 
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("LoginFail");
    }
}
```

Do any of you guys have any idea of whats going wrong?

Comment: I'm able to fetch, alter and delete videos on Youtube. So it's only the upload which fails.

Comment: Did you try using a small and short video file? I often had problems with longer / bigger files?

Comment: The size of the video file is 2,63 MB. It takes 9 sek. to play. So it's not that big :-)

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. But per our [blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow.html), Stack Overflow prides itself in being a destination for questions and answers, and not a place to file bug reports or feature requests. We ask that developers do not post on Stack Overflow for those sorts of things, and instead make use of the templates we have for [filing a bug](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Defect%20Report%29) or [filing a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=Y

Comment: Is there a way you can tap in on the response stream for the web exception? So you can see the full error returned by the web request for result code 500? Or have Fiddler capture the response

Comment: I'm not trying to report a issue/bug. I have a problem uploading a video via the Youtube API and i don't know how to solve it...

Comment: @IbrahimUlukaya Note that backend errors can occur because of client calls (no matter the application), in that sense, this is a valid question.  If the answer is "it was a bug" then the question is "too localized".  If the answer is "you did it wrong, this is how you do it" we welcome that here, as long as it's not something like a syntax error, or anything that makes the question too specialized.

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 is difficult.

Is it possible to get the XML response which may have more detail?
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_error_responses

> A 500 response code indicates that YouTube experienced an error handling a request. You could retry the request at a later time.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Response_Codes

What scope do you use for your oauth2 parameter? Did you try a different YouTube account? Can you try using resumable upload?

The only thing I see that may be an issue is YouTubeRequestSettings() which is a constructor for use of authsub, and you are using oauth2. You can modify the source of the youtube sdk and add a new YouTubeRequestSettings() constructor that uses an oauth2 parameters object instead of just the access key. For an example you can look at the RequestSettings() oauth2 constructor in the gdata sdk.

That's probably not the issue though given you can do other requests, just not upload.

One last idea:
request.Service.InsertAsync(new Uri("http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads"), newVideo.AtomEntry, newVideo);